# Error page (** on Angular routing) not working on Netlify

Tags: angular, angular-routing, netlify

I'm pretty new to Angular so maybe it's not as complicated as it seems to me but I've been working on an Angular project for a website and I created an error page to use when the URL is not correct. As I've seen on other sites, I've configured the **app-routing.module.ts** it as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'cardgrid', component: CardsLayoutComponent},
  {path: 'carddetail', component: CardsDetailComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
  {path: '**', component: ErrorComponent}
];
```

Then I **deployed manually** on **Netlify** using **ng build** to create de **dist** folder, but when I access to an incorrect URL like:

[www.website.netlfiy.app/abcdef](http://www.website.netlfiy.app/abcdef)

The error page doesn't appears, I only see the Netlify 'Page not found' error page. By the way, If I do the same in http://localhost:4200/ it totally works. Even if I try to access:

[www.website.netlfiy.app/*](http://www.website.netlfiy.app/*)*

I can access the error page **only** if I access it through a link, but not tipping it manually. This also works on http://localhost:4200/ only.

I appreciate some help there!
Thank you all :)

Comment: Looks like you did not configure an SPA fallback. Angular knows how to render the 404 page - your server does not. You have to instruct your server to redirect to the index.html when it can't find a resource so that angular can then render the 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

How is your hosting set up?

This sounds like it might be a routing issue.

Two location strategies available, default (html5?) style and hash.

HTML5: `https://example.com/something/else`

Hash: `https://example.com/#/something/else`

The former requires some server-side setup to handle routing, the latter does not.

What's happening:

When you browse to a page, you're literally asking the server to get the html file at that physical location, e.g. `./something/else/index.html` kind of thing.

Therefore, you need to set the server up to redirect anything not found to the root `./index.html`. Given Angular is a SPA - *Single* Page App - the entire site is actually located in just that one `index.html` page at the root.

Hash strategy doesn't need this because servers don't process anything after a `#` character in URLs, so you're always requesting the root index page with your links.

**Note that omitting the `#` or generally browsing to a url that doesn't go anywhere actually still has the same issue - the server can't serve what it doesn't have.**

So even with `#` strategy, ideally you still want to get the server set up properly to always throw that root page out.

[Here we go](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/tips-for-running-an-angular-app-in-iis/). URL rewrite, not redirect, that's the one.

That link will help so long as you're deploying on IIS, have fun Googling for other environments.